# C++ rapidjson Error: free(): invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I am reading in data on JavaScript an pass the Jsonstring like that:`{"data_size":500, "array":[0,0,0,0,..,0,0]}` to the webserver. The numbers in the array could be anything between 0 to 4294967295.

On the Mongoose webserver I am using the lib rapidjson to work with the Jsonstring. Therefore, I create a **Document d** and reads values from the "jsonstring" into an uint32_t Array using this:

```
   #include "rapidjson/document.h"

   int i_data_size=0;
   Document d;

   conn->content[conn->content_len]=0;  //to zero terminate

   if (d.Parse(conn->content).HasParseError())
    {
         //Error
    }
    else
    {


     Value& s = d["data_size"];
     i_data_size=s.GetInt();


       uint32_t *Data=NULL;
       Data=new uint32_t[i_data_size];
       Value& a = d["array"];

       for(SizeType i=0;i<a.Size();i++)
       {
         Data[i]=a[i].GetUint();
       }
    }
```

`conn->content` is containing the json char*.

When I am sending: `{"data_size":500, "array":[0,0,0,0,..,0,0]}`  everything works find. But sometimes, not everytime, when the a number becomes greater, like this:
`{"data_size":500, "array":[123,222,0,0,..,0,0]}`

I get the Error:

**free(): invalid next size (normal)**

Comment: And when the crash happens, what is the value of `a.Size()`? My bet is that the size is more than `500`. And is there a reason you don't use e.g. a vector and push back the values and let it grow as needed?

Comment: In which line are you getting that error? I don't think there is anything wrong with the way you are reading the document unless the size of array in your json document is greater than 500.

Comment: a.Size() = 500. Anytime for that Jsonstring

Comment: The problem occurs, when I first send  {"array":[0,0,0,0,0,0,..,0]} and then change any numbers to e.g.  {"array":[1111,0,0,0,0,0,..,0]}

Comment: Please explain more clear how are you changing things? I think the code you provided is not everything you are actually doing, complete your sample code so then we can get what you are doing exactly

Comment: Updated the question: Hope this is more clear. The error is spontanious..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem!

Writing a zero out of the boundry was causing the error:

```
conn->content[conn->content_len]=0;  //to zero terminate
```

Solved the problem by using a string instead:

```
  string json="";
    json = string(conn->content);
    json=json.substr(0,conn->content_len);

  if (d.Parse(json.c_str()).HasParseError())
  { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to rapidJson it is from C, showing because something is messed up with memory management. C++, the heir to the language C, won't check anything regarding to memory management because it supposed to be fast and it will trust you with this. Because of that, the error you are getting won't just tell you what is wrong exactly. In your code, you are using an array but you are not managing its boundaries well, double check what you are doing regarding to reading and writing that unsigned array (check boundaries more carefully) or use a container like std::vector which will do that for you. Take a look at here:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm